# Fedora arm - Orange Pi plus 2e

Tags: linux, arm, fedora, orange-pi

I have Orange Pi Plus 2e.

I want to install Fedora 24 on it.

So from
https://arm.fedoraproject.org/
I download "Fedora minimal"
https://download.fed...-1.2-sda.raw.xz

Next I unpack it:

```
xz -d Fedora-Minimal-armhfp-24-1.2-sda.raw.xz
```

and write to micro sdhc card:

```
dd if=Fedora-Minimal-armhfp-24-1.2-sda.raw of=/dev/my_micro_sdhc_card
```

(I write it to card, not to partition on card).

I have new partitions on this card like:
boot
/
swap

I put my card to Orange and turn it on, but it does not load Fedora.

Does anyone know how to do it, has any experience, can share some knowledge, links with me ?

Comment: This Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It **may** be more appropriate on the S.E. related site http://unix.stackexchange.com (Unix & Linux). Consider using the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. Thanks and Good Luck.

Comment: Before posting  more questions on StackOverflow, please read http://stackoverflow.com/tour , http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask , and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Fedora offers a script to write the disk image as well as board specific U-Boot and dtb. You can find more information here - https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Architectures/ARM/F24/Installation#Fedora_Arm_Installer . Be sure to use the latest version in updates-testing (fedora-arm-installer-1.99.12-1.fc24).

We would appreciate feedback or any issues you encounter, you can visit us in #fedora-arm on Freenode or send to our mailing list - https://admin.fedoraproject.org/mailman/listinfo/arm

Paul

Comment: It would be great to use fedora-arm-installer but I do not see it supports Orange Pi Plus 2e.